# Index is used in PostgreSQL but not in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

(question from [slack](https://join.slack.com/t/yugabyte-db/shared_invite/zt-xbd652e9-3tN0N7UG0eLpsace4t1d2A))
The following script uses the index in the last select on postgres but not on yugabyte.

```
drop table if exists entry2;
CREATE TABLE entry2 (comp_id  int,
                     path varchar,
                     index varchar,
                     archtype varchar,
                     other JSONB,
                     PRIMARY KEY (comp_id, path,index));
DO $$
    BEGIN
        FOR counter IN 1..200000 BY 1 LOOP

                insert into entry2 values (counter,'/content[open XXX- XXX-OBSERVATION.blood_pressure.v1,0]','0','open XXX- XXX-OBSERVATION.blood_pressure.v1','{"data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value/value" :132,"data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0005]/value/value": 92}');
                insert into entry2 values (counter,'/content[open XXX- XXX-OBSERVATION.blood_pressure.v1,0]','1','open XXX- XXX-OBSERVATION.blood_pressure.v1',('{"data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value/value" :'||(130+ counter) ||',"data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0005]/value/value": 90}')::jsonb);
                insert into entry2 values (counter,'/content[open XXX- XXX-OBSERVATION.heart_rate-pulse.v1,0]','0','open XXX- XXX-OBSERVATION.heart_rate-pulse.v1','{"data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value/value" :132,"/data[at0002]/events[at0003]/data[at0001]/items[at0004]/value/value": 113}');
            END LOOP;
    END; $$;



drop index if exists blood_pr;
create index  blood_pr on entry2(((other ->> 'data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value/value')::integer ));

explain analyse
select  (other ->> 'data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value/value')::integer  from entry2
where    (other ->> 'data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value/value')::integer > 140
order by (other ->> 'data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value/value')::integer::integer
limit 10
;
```

PostgreSQL uses the index to avoid a sort and then get immediately the first 10 rows

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL the index is used to avoid a sort because the order of the index is the same as the `order by`. Sorted indexes (B-Tree) are the default in PostgreSQL but not in YugabyteDB which is a distributed SQL database where indexes are hash-sharded by default on the first column. You can create it as range-sharded with `ASC` or `DESC`:

```
create index  blood_pr on entry2(((other ->> 'data[at0001]/events[at0006]/data[at0003]/items[at0004]/value/value')::integer ) ASC);
```